# How did I inadvertently create a denial-of-service with ServiceStack and Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack

Given the following code from my service:

```
namespace LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime
{
    [Route("/leadpost")]
    public class PrimeLeadImportAdapter : IReturn<LeadInformationResponse>
    {
        public LeadInformation LeadInformation { get; set; }
    }

    public class LeadInformation
    {
        public LeadApplication LeadApplication { get; set; }    
    }

    public class LeadApplication
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class LeadInformationResponse
    {
        public long TimeTakenMs { get; set; }
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } 
    }
}


public class PrimeLeadServices : Service
{
    public object Any(LeadInformation request)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        PublishMessage<LeadInformation>(request);

        var response = new LeadInformationResponse
        {
            TimeTakenMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
        };

        return response;
    }
}

public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
    container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());

    //Register MQ Broker Service
    var mqService = new RedisMqServer(container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>());
    container.Register<IMessageService>(mqService);
    container.Register(mqService.MessageFactory);

    mqService.RegisterHandler<LeadInformation>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);

    mqService.Start();
}
```

and this code (run as a test or console):

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:61992/json/reply/LeadInformation");
var receipt = client.Post(new LeadInformation
{
    LeadApplication = new LeadApplication
    {
        FirstName = "Stephen",
        LastName = "Patten",
        Email = "foo@example.com",
    }

});
receipt.PrintDump();
```

When I POST to the endpoint, Redis via MONITOR, goes into a tailspin so to speak and seems to be bombarded by the same commands being issued over and over.

Here is a sample:

```
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LTRIM" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "0" "100"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:out" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"a93a8dad3661428cab58d8bf410e6060\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257214)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"c35ed994935d463b8640f5c6cfb0991d\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50749] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformation.inq" "{\"Id\":\"f5262b2d713946ba96c21f4dee6ccaa9\",\"CreatedDate\"
:\"\\/Date(1412368257214)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"Options\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceMode
l.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformation, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",\"LeadApplication\":{\"TrackingId\":0,\"InitialStatus\":0,\"TestL
ead\":false,\"ProductType\":0,\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Patten\",\"ConsumerEnvironmentId\":0,\"Email\":\"stephen.patt
en@gmail.com\",\"MonthsEmployed\":0,\"IsRetired\":false,\"IsSelfEmployed\":false,\"MonthlyIncome\":0,\"MonthlyExpenses\":0,\"Rent\":
0,\"SupplementalIncome\":0,\"IsInDebtProgram\":false,\"BankABA\":false,\"BankAccountTermInMonths\":0,\"HasDirectDeposit\":false,\"Ha
sMovedRecently\":false,\"HasAgreedToEft\":false,\"IsHomeOwner\":false,\"AgreedToDialerTCPA\":false}}}"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "{\"Id\":\"a93a8dad3661428cab58d8bf410e6060\",\"Crea
tedDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257214)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"c35ed994935d463b8640f5c6cfb0991d\",\"Option
s\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\"
,\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LTRIM" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "0" "100"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"177e8c0ba22a49cebef99f523dadc969\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257214)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"2988c8b3803e4bd09a6259d8e89eeac9\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:out" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.214613 [0 127.0.0.1:50749] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformation.inq" "{\"Id\":\"9c2d8cd60f6043e999c910807c12f18e\",\"CreatedDate\"
:\"\\/Date(1412368257215)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"Options\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceMode
l.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformation, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",\"LeadApplication\":{\"TrackingId\":0,\"InitialStatus\":0,\"TestL
ead\":false,\"ProductType\":0,\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Patten\",\"ConsumerEnvironmentId\":0,\"Email\":\"stephen.patt
en@gmail.com\",\"MonthsEmployed\":0,\"IsRetired\":false,\"IsSelfEmployed\":false,\"MonthlyIncome\":0,\"MonthlyExpenses\":0,\"Rent\":
0,\"SupplementalIncome\":0,\"IsInDebtProgram\":false,\"BankABA\":false,\"BankAccountTermInMonths\":0,\"HasDirectDeposit\":false,\"Ha
sMovedRecently\":false,\"HasAgreedToEft\":false,\"IsHomeOwner\":false,\"AgreedToDialerTCPA\":false}}}"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"31693bdbc31c473ab1d4f96713038480\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257215)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"1e3896884da244618f35e6620ac177b7\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "{\"Id\":\"177e8c0ba22a49cebef99f523dadc969\",\"Crea
tedDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257214)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"2988c8b3803e4bd09a6259d8e89eeac9\",\"Option
s\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\"
,\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LTRIM" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "0" "100"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50749] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:out" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformation.inq" "{\"Id\":\"4d386184ef0c4d61934a7adfd46cf4eb\",\"CreatedDate\"
:\"\\/Date(1412368257215)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"Options\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceMode
l.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformation, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",\"LeadApplication\":{\"TrackingId\":0,\"InitialStatus\":0,\"TestL
ead\":false,\"ProductType\":0,\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Patten\",\"ConsumerEnvironmentId\":0,\"Email\":\"stephen.patt
en@gmail.com\",\"MonthsEmployed\":0,\"IsRetired\":false,\"IsSelfEmployed\":false,\"MonthlyIncome\":0,\"MonthlyExpenses\":0,\"Rent\":
0,\"SupplementalIncome\":0,\"IsInDebtProgram\":false,\"BankABA\":false,\"BankAccountTermInMonths\":0,\"HasDirectDeposit\":false,\"Ha
sMovedRecently\":false,\"HasAgreedToEft\":false,\"IsHomeOwner\":false,\"AgreedToDialerTCPA\":false}}}"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.215613 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"ee3cd0823e2442fcb27844aedac063c1\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257215)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"f5262b2d713946ba96c21f4dee6ccaa9\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "{\"Id\":\"31693bdbc31c473ab1d4f96713038480\",\"Crea
tedDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257215)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"1e3896884da244618f35e6620ac177b7\",\"Option
s\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\"
,\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "LTRIM" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "0" "100"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50749] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:out" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformation.inq" "{\"Id\":\"6cd5b97f72d84cec945938b4e9f8bc5d\",\"CreatedDate\"
:\"\\/Date(1412368257216)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"Options\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceMode
l.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformation, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",\"LeadApplication\":{\"TrackingId\":0,\"InitialStatus\":0,\"TestL
ead\":false,\"ProductType\":0,\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Patten\",\"ConsumerEnvironmentId\":0,\"Email\":\"stephen.patt
en@gmail.com\",\"MonthsEmployed\":0,\"IsRetired\":false,\"IsSelfEmployed\":false,\"MonthlyIncome\":0,\"MonthlyExpenses\":0,\"Rent\":
0,\"SupplementalIncome\":0,\"IsInDebtProgram\":false,\"BankABA\":false,\"BankAccountTermInMonths\":0,\"HasDirectDeposit\":false,\"Ha
sMovedRecently\":false,\"HasAgreedToEft\":false,\"IsHomeOwner\":false,\"AgreedToDialerTCPA\":false}}}"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"2d110ee0da044069a8cf354c804c734b\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257216)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"9c2d8cd60f6043e999c910807c12f18e\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "{\"Id\":\"ee3cd0823e2442fcb27844aedac063c1\",\"Crea
tedDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257215)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"f5262b2d713946ba96c21f4dee6ccaa9\",\"Option
s\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\"
,\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50749] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LTRIM" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "0" "100"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:out" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq"
1412368257.216615 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformation.inq" "{\"Id\":\"ab13d13e538445fe8a8ee67c795066ed\",\"CreatedDate\"
:\"\\/Date(1412368257216)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"Options\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceMode
l.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformation, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",\"LeadApplication\":{\"TrackingId\":0,\"InitialStatus\":0,\"TestL
ead\":false,\"ProductType\":0,\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Patten\",\"ConsumerEnvironmentId\":0,\"Email\":\"stephen.patt
en@gmail.com\",\"MonthsEmployed\":0,\"IsRetired\":false,\"IsSelfEmployed\":false,\"MonthlyIncome\":0,\"MonthlyExpenses\":0,\"Rent\":
0,\"SupplementalIncome\":0,\"IsInDebtProgram\":false,\"BankABA\":false,\"BankAccountTermInMonths\":0,\"HasDirectDeposit\":false,\"Ha
sMovedRecently\":false,\"HasAgreedToEft\":false,\"IsHomeOwner\":false,\"AgreedToDialerTCPA\":false}}}"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"7c4f3bff200f414c8ed664323033d7d5\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257217)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"4d386184ef0c4d61934a7adfd46cf4eb\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50749] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "{\"Id\":\"2d110ee0da044069a8cf354c804c734b\",\"Crea
tedDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257216)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"9c2d8cd60f6043e999c910807c12f18e\",\"Option
s\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\"
,\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "LTRIM" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "0" "100"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:out" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformation.inq" "{\"Id\":\"d2069fad518748559e625df43b41823d\",\"CreatedDate\"
:\"\\/Date(1412368257217)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"Options\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceMode
l.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformation, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",\"LeadApplication\":{\"TrackingId\":0,\"InitialStatus\":0,\"TestL
ead\":false,\"ProductType\":0,\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Patten\",\"ConsumerEnvironmentId\":0,\"Email\":\"stephen.patt
en@gmail.com\",\"MonthsEmployed\":0,\"IsRetired\":false,\"IsSelfEmployed\":false,\"MonthlyIncome\":0,\"MonthlyExpenses\":0,\"Rent\":
0,\"SupplementalIncome\":0,\"IsInDebtProgram\":false,\"BankABA\":false,\"BankAccountTermInMonths\":0,\"HasDirectDeposit\":false,\"Ha
sMovedRecently\":false,\"HasAgreedToEft\":false,\"IsHomeOwner\":false,\"AgreedToDialerTCPA\":false}}}"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"27840eecacbf43aaa3a0d7609a623c0f\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257217)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"6cd5b97f72d84cec945938b4e9f8bc5d\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.217615 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "{\"Id\":\"7c4f3bff200f414c8ed664323033d7d5\",\"Crea
tedDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257217)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"4d386184ef0c4d61934a7adfd46cf4eb\",\"Option
s\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\"
,\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50749] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LTRIM" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "0" "100"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:out" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformation.inq" "{\"Id\":\"2148d02eab7944858f5a2999046b5d2d\",\"CreatedDate\"
:\"\\/Date(1412368257218)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"Options\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceMode
l.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformation, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",\"LeadApplication\":{\"TrackingId\":0,\"InitialStatus\":0,\"TestL
ead\":false,\"ProductType\":0,\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Patten\",\"ConsumerEnvironmentId\":0,\"Email\":\"stephen.patt
en@gmail.com\",\"MonthsEmployed\":0,\"IsRetired\":false,\"IsSelfEmployed\":false,\"MonthlyIncome\":0,\"MonthlyExpenses\":0,\"Rent\":
0,\"SupplementalIncome\":0,\"IsInDebtProgram\":false,\"BankABA\":false,\"BankAccountTermInMonths\":0,\"HasDirectDeposit\":false,\"Ha
sMovedRecently\":false,\"HasAgreedToEft\":false,\"IsHomeOwner\":false,\"AgreedToDialerTCPA\":false}}}"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"24d3690beaab4441b2f5958f86cbc510\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257218)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"ab13d13e538445fe8a8ee67c795066ed\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "{\"Id\":\"27840eecacbf43aaa3a0d7609a623c0f\",\"Crea
tedDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257217)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"6cd5b97f72d84cec945938b4e9f8bc5d\",\"Option
s\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\"
,\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50747] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50749] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "LTRIM" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "0" "100"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50754] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:out" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50728] "RPOP" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformation.inq" "{\"Id\":\"4ec3dd7a500a4b18a8e16568b43d10b3\",\"CreatedDate\"
:\"\\/Date(1412368257218)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"Options\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceMode
l.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformation, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",\"LeadApplication\":{\"TrackingId\":0,\"InitialStatus\":0,\"TestL
ead\":false,\"ProductType\":0,\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Patten\",\"ConsumerEnvironmentId\":0,\"Email\":\"stephen.patt
en@gmail.com\",\"MonthsEmployed\":0,\"IsRetired\":false,\"IsSelfEmployed\":false,\"MonthlyIncome\":0,\"MonthlyExpenses\":0,\"Rent\":
0,\"SupplementalIncome\":0,\"IsInDebtProgram\":false,\"BankABA\":false,\"BankAccountTermInMonths\":0,\"HasDirectDeposit\":false,\"Ha
sMovedRecently\":false,\"HasAgreedToEft\":false,\"IsHomeOwner\":false,\"AgreedToDialerTCPA\":false}}}"
1412368257.218616 [0 127.0.0.1:50752] "PUBLISH" "mq:topic:in" "mq:LeadInformation.inq"
1412368257.219617 [0 127.0.0.1:50751] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.inq" "{\"Id\":\"e899c4d7488848eab9d3bc31d9045ad7\",\"Creat
edDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257219)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"d2069fad518748559e625df43b41823d\",\"Options
\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\",
\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
1412368257.219617 [0 127.0.0.1:50753] "LPUSH" "mq:LeadInformationResponse.outq" "{\"Id\":\"24d3690beaab4441b2f5958f86cbc510\",\"Crea
tedDate\":\"\\/Date(1412368257218)\\/\",\"Priority\":0,\"RetryAttempts\":0,\"ReplyId\":\"ab13d13e538445fe8a8ee67c795066ed\",\"Option
s\":1,\"Body\":{\"__type\":\"LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel.Adapters.Prime.LeadInformationResponse, LO.Leads.Receiver.ServiceModel\"
,\"TimeTakenMs\":0}}"
```

So my question is what have I done wrong? It seems to mimic the demo/tests code published on the ServiceStack site. I have run A LOT of the tests included with SS and none of them exhibit this problem. stumped.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This publishes the `LeadInformation` message to itself, indefinitely:

```
public class PrimeLeadServices : Service
{
    public object Any(LeadInformation request)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        // This publishes a message that re-calls this service again
        PublishMessage<LeadInformation>(request);

        var response = new LeadInformationResponse
        {
            TimeTakenMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
        };

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Crap! I had started with the Reusability SMessageService and questioned why the IMessageFactory property was there as it's in Service base class, right? So that started me refactoring journey that didn't end too well. Have a great day mythz and thank you :)